# Run Jersey in my existing server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I have a server which access DB and uses Apache MINA for managing connections.

I would like to expand this server and allow it to handle REST requests and I would like that every REST resource will have access to my server's context.

I have started implementing a Dynamic Web Application using Jersey 1.18 using Tomcat as container.

But I cannot figure out how to combine my server with the web service...

Is there a way to initialize the Jersey stack inside my custom service and avoid the Tomcat ??

I hope my question makes sense...

Thank you,

Oren

Comment: Jersey is essentially a servlet, so it is possible to add the jersey servlet to an existing servlet container.  Do you have an existing servlet container?  If you wanted to embed one, you could use Jetty.

Comment: Does it makes sense to run Jetty and Apache MINA on the same JVM process?? eventually I would like my servlet resources to have access to my main server which holds different application logic and resources.

Comment: For Jersey, you need a servlet engine. My understanding of MINA was it was lower-level than a servlet engine (but my knowledge of MINA is extremely cursory).